# How to get a directive consumed

Tags: typescript, angular, browserify

Compiling from TypeScript with Browserify...I'm writing a UDM that injects new DOM elements into the page dynamically...I'd like to apply an NG2 @Directive() to them, but not being "called" from anywhere else in the code, the compile process bypasses the directive's `import`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish and what you have tried and where you failed. What is "UDM that injects new DOM elements into the page dynamically"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply directives to elements in a component, you need to specify them in its `directives` attribute:

```
import { SomeDirective } from './some.directive';

@Component({
  (...)
  directives: [ SomeDirective ]
})
export class SomeComponent {
  (...)
}
```

In this case, the import won't be bypassed during compilation. If you don't specify the directive in the attribute, it would be the case...